# Trouble with hasManyThrough in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, has-many-through, eloquent

Maybe dublicate, but my search hasn't any success. What we have:
Laravel 5.2, three tables

**user_tariff_hours_history**

- id
- user_tariff_id
- ...

**user_tariff**

- id
- user_id
- ...

**users**

- id
- ...

I want to get **user** through **user_tariff** for current **user_tariff_hours_history**

As official Laravel Docs said I need to have getter with the hasManyThrough method in my user_tariff_hours_history's model https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

But result of the query with that getter didn't expected.

I get whole **users** table, not a user for current **user_tariff_hours_history**

getter:

```
    public function getUsers() {

    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\SARegistration',
                                 'App\SAUser_tariff',
                                    'user_id', //FK on SARegistration (users)
                                    'id', //Local Key of ?
                                    'user_tariff_id'); //FK on SAUser_tariff (user_tariffs)

}
```

Note: in docs there are 6 params for the hasManyThrough, but Laravel said it has only 5 params, than I was trying to use diffirent combo of params

Answer (score 0):

Define `hasManyThrough` relationship called `userTariffHoursHistory` in `User` model and use `whereHas()`:

```
User::whereHas('userTariffHoursHistory', function($q) use($userTariffHoursHistoryId) {
    $q->where('id', $userTariffHoursHistoryId);
})->first();
```

Or define two `hasMany()` relationships (`userTariffs` in `User` model and `userTariffHoursHistory` in `UserTariff` model) and then use nested `whereHas()`:

```
User::whereHas('userTariffs', function($q) use($userTariffHoursHistoryId) {
    $q->whereHas('userTariffHoursHistory', function($q) use($userTariffHoursHistoryId) {
        $q->where('id', $userTariffHoursHistoryId);
    });
})->first();
```

Comment: Can we make it using relationship (getter) in userTariffHoursHistory model ?

Comment: You don't want to do that since your goal is getting a user instance.

Comment: My goal is get userTariffHoursHistory data with joined users through userTariffs, so, I cannot imagine it if we haven't getter for users in userTariffHoursHistory

Comment: If you want to get the user, use the code from my answer. If you also want to also add history for the user, add `->with('userTariffHoursHistory')` to the query.

Comment: Can you show me plain SQL from your answer in case "to add history also" for my understanding of your idea?